# saga() function not invoking on re-login

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

Hi I am trying to create an app with authentication and authorization. I am using redux saga for it. Now when I try to login for the first time this saga fuction is invoked:

```
 export function* saga() {
    yield takeLatest(actionTypes.Login, function* loginSaga() {
        yield getUserByToken();
        yield put(actions.requestUser());
      });
}
```

Now when I login for the second time it does not get invoked. I have to refresh my page.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is the actions:

```
export const actions = {
      login: (authToken) => ({ type: actionTypes.Login, payload: { authToken } }),
      register: (authToken) => ({
        type: actionTypes.Register,
        payload: { authToken },
      }),
      logout: () => ({ type: actionTypes.Logout }),
      requestUser: (user) => ({
        type: actionTypes.UserRequested,
        payload: { user },
      }),
      fulfillUser: (user) => ({ type: actionTypes.UserLoaded, payload: { user } }),
    };
```

Comment: any solution to above problem ?